# Illegal assignment to class mtiUvm.uvm_pkg::uvm_component

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I get this error when trying to access the uvm_config_db to access a variable. I googled it and found the following answer on the accellera forums:

http://forums.accellera.org/topic/406-compilation-error-regarding-illegal-class-assignment/

**You cannot use this as a context inside a sequence; you must rely on the full sequence name.**

Can anyone explain why this is so?
Thanks

Comment: Edit your question to be more specific. Leave the link in there, but add your code in there as well to make it easier for people reading the question to exactly understand what the problem is. Remember, the goal is not just to get your question answered for you, but so other people can benefit in the future as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you pass for a context to `uvm_config_db::get/set`, in your case `this`, must refer to a UVM component. Based on the value of `context` the path of full hierarchical path of where the config setting applies is constructed. If `this` is a sequence (which does not inherit from `uvm_component`, then it will have not fixed hierarchy.

What I usually do in sequences is:

```
uvm_config_db #(some_type)::get(p_sequencer, "", "some_field", some_field);
```

`p_sequencer` is a UVM component and you can make config settings apply to any sequence started on that sequencer.